# Doctype crashing my JSF

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, doctype

I am new in JSF. I'm testing an adaptive table plugin. works perfectly without any Doctype , but if I put a Doctype and the browser is narrower than 800px the table doesn't appears (@media should call the narrow version of the table, but it does not). I would like to set Doctype in my xhtml.
Using Primefaces 3.5 & Mojarra 2.1.14.

Here is the code:

**tabla.xhtml**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>  
    <meta name="viewport" content = "width = device-width" />
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="stackStyle.css" />
    <h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js" target="head" />
    <h:outputScript library="js" name="stacktable.js" />
    <h:outputScript library="js" name="estilito.js" />
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="responsive.css" />  
</h:head>
<h:body> 
    <p:tabView id="tabView" style="width:80%; margin:2em auto">  
        <p:tab title="Part I">  
            <p:outputPanel styleClass="container ui-datatable-tablewrapper">
                <h:form prependId="false">
                    <p:dataTable styleClass="large-only" id="tablaResponsiva" cellspacing="0" var="car" value="#{tablesBean.cars}">
                        <p:column>
                            <f:facet name="header"  >
                                <h:outputText value="Usuarios" /> 
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{car.model}"  />
                        </p:column>             
                        <p:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="Manufacturer" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{car.manufacturer}"  />
                        </p:column>             
                        <p:column>
                            <f:facet name="header" >
                                <h:outputText value="Other Information" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{car.otherInformation}" />
                        </p:column>
                    </p:dataTable>
                    <h:outputScript target="body">
                          $("#tabview\\:tablaResponsiva").stacktable({myClass:'stacktable small-only'});
                    </h:outputScript>
                </h:form>
            </p:outputPanel>
        </p:tab>   
    </p:tabView>       
</h:body>
```

If necessary could also attach JS and CSS files.

Thank you very much in advance.

*I tested the 3 xhtml 1.0 Doctypes (strict, transitional and frameset). I also tested the xhtml 1.1 Doctypes (basic and DTD). I have no preference for any doctype. I would just like to have one and run the resizable script.

Comment: You forgot to tell what doctype exactly you'd like to set.

Comment: use the current html doctype i.e. `<!doctype html>`

Comment: Tested also the HTML5 doctype <!DOCTYPE HTML>. It does not work either.

Comment: No more ideas? I could not solve it yet.